# How can I get my fava beans to grow faster and start flowering?

Tags: vegetables, growth, flowering, container-gardening, fava-beans

I planted some fava beans in large pots late october. They should be flowering by now, but all I can see is small flower buds, only in a couple of the plants. And it is growing very slowly. What can I do to help them?

[image]

Comment: Is there something you would like me to add to my answer?

Answer (score 2):

They're not getting enough sun. Your plants are [etiolated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiolation). They want at least six straight hours of direct sunlight, minimum. 8-12 is better. Move them to a sunnier spot.

Also, in a pot, you want to use potting mix, not garden soil. This is because of drainage issues in the very different environment, mostly. Next time, you can use a quality potting mix, and fertilize regularly for best results.

Lastly, they're crowded. In a pot that size, you can't really grow more than two fava bean plants to maturity, one's a better idea. Even though they don't look super close, in a pot, the roots can't spread outward very far, like they do in a garden bed. Putting multiple plants in the pot will only exacerbate the problem. You should thin to only one or two of the healthiest plants per pot.

I do see flower buds, but those plants are rather spindly to be producing fruit right now. If you can try to improve the conditions as stated above, you may have a better chance.